# The checkboxes in the vue js loop do not work correctly

Tags: laravel, vue.js, checkbox, v-for

When using v-for, I need to allocate a number of materials with a checkbox. But when you click on the checkbox, a group of materials is immediately highlighted. This is due to the fact that the Quantity parameter is the same for many materials. How do I make sure that when I click on the checkbox, only one material is highlighted and the Quantity value is added to checkedMaterials?[image]

```
 <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Material name</th>
                <th>Количество</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="material in materials">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" :value="material" v-model="checkedMaterials">
                        {{material.id}}
                    </td>{{ material.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ material.Quantity }}</td>
                </tr>
export default {
name: "Show",

data() {
    return {
        materials: '',
        checkedMaterials: [],
    }
},

mounted() {
    this.getPart()
    this.getMaterials()
},

methods: {
    getPart() {
        axios.get(`/api/part/${this.$route.params.id}`).then(res => {
            this.part = res.data.data
        })
    },

    getMaterials() {
        axios.get('/api/material').then(res => {
            this.materials = res.data.data;
            })
       },
  },
```

}

Comment: Your code should work perfectly. I did not see any issue in that. Here, I created a demo fiddle for the reference : https://jsfiddle.net/hcd1o4f7/

Answer (score 1):

1. take id as value instead of whole material.

   ```
             <tr v-for="material in materials">
                  <td><input type="checkbox" :value="material.id" v-model="checkedMaterials">
                      {{material.id}}
                  </td>{{ material.name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ material.Quantity }}</td>
              </tr>
   ```
2. make computed propery for getting quantity .

   ```
    computed : {

        allSelectedMaterial() {
            return this.materials.filter((material) => 
                    this.checkedMaterials.includes(material.id) )
        },
        selectedMaterialQuantitry(){
             return this.allSelectedMaterial.map((material) => material.quantity)
        },
        uniqueSelectedQuantity(){
          return [...new Set(this.selectedMaterialQuantitry)]
        }
     },
   ```

code : https://jsfiddle.net/d9nwz4kt/35/

Comment: meet vaghsiya, rhank you very much!!!!

Comment: It's my pleasure!!